# What are the differences between hyperledger documentation and openblockchain docmentation?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am new to hyperledger fabric so I started with the documentation.
Hyperledger Fabric Documentation: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io

I found one more readthedocs which is explaining the fabric too.
https://openblockchain.readthedocs.io

What are the differences between them and which I should prefer as developer?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the same thing (They explain about Hyperledger Fabric), but the official docs of Hyperledger Fabric its more practical, you have the First Network tutorial, chaincode tutorials, etc, and the Open Fabric Docs its like more theorical.

Answer (score 0):

OpenBlockchain is for Fabric 0.6, which is no longer being worked on.